# Access database from postgres backend extension in C

Tags: sql, c, postgresql

I'm writing postgres backend extension in C. I would like to store configuration of my extension inside database table. Is there any possibility to access a database table from that extension or I need to implement postgres client to do that?

Comment: I don't understand what "access specific table from that extension" and "implement postgres client" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration for extensions is solved via custom configuration variables usually - good example is auto_explain extensions (inside PostgreSQL contrib). If you need a access to database storage, then you should to use a SPI API - Stored Procedure Interface.

- https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/contrib/auto_explain
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/spi.html

Comment: You are the first person who actually helped me on stack. Thanks.

Comment: @Logman: a http://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-hackers/ pgsql-hackers mailing list is good platform, where you can get a reply to your questions.